# Android Studio AVD emulator

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a problem with my emulator guys, if anyone knows how to fix this I would appreciate a lot. It is not displaying on scale, the interface appears on the left top corner on the emulated device and not on full screen. I have downloaded the latest ver of adroind with api level 26, tried both x86 and x64 versions, same problem, have all the necessary SDK tools installed and still not working, not sure why its not displaying corectly.

Kind Regards!